# Use jQuery to check percentage width of div and perform conditional style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got ten instances of .progress. All of which have percentage based widths.

If any given instance of .progress is over 100% width, I'd like to style it's backround red and then force to 100% width.

Any help?

This was my feeble attempt.

```
if ($( '.progress' ).css("width") > '100%') {
     $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
     // or $(this).addClass('red');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think width in `%` is not available in js so i think you should try to check the target's width to its parent's width:

```
if ($('.progress').css("width") >== $('.progress').parent().css("width")) {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
   // or $(this).addClass('red');
}
```

---

or this way:

```
$('.progress').each(function(){
   var $target = $(this);
   if ($target.css("width") >== $target.parent().css("width")) {
      $target.css('background-color', 'red');
      // or $target.addClass('red');
   }
});
```

or this way

```
$('.progress').css('background-color', function(_, color) {
    return $(this).width() > $(this).parent().width() ? 'red' : color;
});
```

Comment: +1 was just typing that, `> '100%'` makes no sense, but you forgot that there's ten instances of `.progress`

Comment: @adeneo yeah i was updating this one with a `.each()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '.progress' ).each(function() {
var $this = $(this);

if ($this.css("width") > '100%') {
     $this.css({
        'background-color':  'red',
        'width' : '100%'
     });
}
});
```

or

```
$( '.progress' ).each(function() {
var $this = $(this);

if (( 100 * parseFloat($this.css('width')) / parseFloat($this.parent().css('width')) ) > '100%') {
     $this.css({
        'background-color':  'red',
        'width' : '100%'
     });
}
});
```